# Как увеличить диапазон функции rand

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы выдавало большое случайное число. Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
__int64 p= 489133282872437279;
__int64 s = rand() % p + 1;
```

Но почему-то rand выдает маленькие значения. Это потому, что RAND_MAX = 32767. Как его можно увеличить?

Comment: Воспользоваться возможностями C++11 - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: Или открыть 3 томик Кнута и найти нужный алгоритм и закодить

Comment: Вызвать rand несколько раз

Comment: @KoVadim В третьем томе - сортировка и поиск...

Comment: да, спутал, не томик третий, а глава третья (а она  в втором томе)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно лучше воспользоваться какой-нибудь библиотекой, но если это учебная программа то можно и самому реализовать.

В основе `rand()` лежит [линейный конгруэнтный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4). Реализация которого примерно такая:

```
#define RAND_MAX 32767 

static unsigned long int next = 1;


int rand(void)
{
  next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
  return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % (RAND_MAX + 1);
}

void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
  next = seed;
}
```

Как можно видеть отсюда, поменять диапазон очень легко: нужно `RAND_MAX` заменить на свое число и поменять `int` на `long long int`.

---

Но `rand()` достаточно "туповат" если реализовывать то лучше взять [вихрь мерсена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0) у него лучше статистическая устойчивость и он достаточно прост в реализации.

Answer (score 2):

Когда-то давно я писал вот такое на основе Кнутового "Искусства программирования":

```
class Random
{
public:
    typedef int RandomValue;
    Random& operator = (int seed) { X = seed; return *this; }
    Random(int seed = 1):X(seed){};
    int operator()(int seed = 0)
    {
        const int MM = 2147483647;
        const int AA =      48271;
        const int QQ =      44488;
        const int RR =       3399;
        if (seed != 0) X = seed;
        X = AA*(X%QQ)-RR*(X/QQ);
        if (X < 0) X += MM;
        return X-1;
    }
    int operator()(int min, int max)
    {
        return (*this)()%(max-min) + min;
    }
private:
    int X;
};

class Random64
{
typedef unsigned long long uint64;
public:
    typedef uint64 RandomValue;
    Random64& operator = (uint64 seed) { X = seed; return *this; }
    Random64(uint64 seed = 0):X(seed){};
    uint64 operator()(uint64 seed = uint64(-1))
    {
        const uint64 a = 3202034522624059733ULL;
        const uint64 c =                   1ULL;

        if (seed != uint64(-1)) X = seed;
        uint64 Y = a * X + c;
        X = a * Y + c;
        Y = (Y&0xFFFFFFFF00000000ULL) | (X >> 32);
        return Y;
    }
    uint64 operator()(uint64 min, uint64 max)
    {
        return (*this)()%(max-min) + min;
    }
private:
    uint64 X;
};
```

Думаю, как пользовать, понятно?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете :

1. Воспользоваться сторонней библиотекой: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_random.html
2. Сделать нечто подобное:
   Рандомом получить a;
   Рандомом получить b;
   И сделать некую сумму: `a * (RAND_MAX + 1) + b;`

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы рандомное число не превышало p

Comment: а если получить огромное число с помощью варианта 2 и сделать `(a * (RAND_MAX + 1) + b) % p` если результрующая сумма больше p?